# ts-node: Unexpected token ':'

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node

I am writing a backend server for my app and decided to change **babel-node** executor to **ts-node**. My command in **package.json** is:

```
"server": "cd server && ts-node --project tsconfig.json -r ts-node/register Server.ts",
```

But keep getting the same error:

```
> nodejs-server@1.0.0 server D:\Projects\Visual Studio Code\NodeJS Server
> cd server && ts-node --project tsconfig.json -r ts-node/register Server.ts

(node:3824) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:83:18)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:36:21)
```

I tried compiling a small file, but compiler does not understand typescript.

**test.ts**:

```
var test: string = 'Hello!';
console.log(test);
```

I get the same error:

```
PS D:\Projects\Visual Studio Code\NodeJS Server\server> npx ts-node test.ts
(node:1420) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:83:18)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:36:21)
```

I have already reinstalled **ts-node** and **typescript** modules.

Root **tsconfig.json**:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "traceResolution": false,
        "allowJs": false,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "noResolve": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "sourceMap": false,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "typeRoots": [
            "custom_typings",
            "node_modules/@types",
        ],
    },
    "include": [
        "client",
        "server",
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "client/bundle.js"
    ]
}
```

**server/tsconfig.json**:

```
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "noEmit": true,
        "baseUrl": "../",
        "paths": {
            "*": ["node_modules/*"],
            "@server/*": ["server/*"],
            "@client/*": ["client/*"],
            "@routes/*": ["server/routes/*"],
            "@public/*": ["public/*"],
            "@secure/*": ["secure/*"],
            "@utils/*": ["utils/*"],
        },
    },
    "include": ["**/*"]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution.
In the project configuration (file **package.json**) it was necessary to remove the modular type of work JS.

Line: `"type": "module",`

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename: `Server.js` to `Server.ts`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a tsconfig, make sure nothing is set to "ESNext".  This could be either the `target` or `module` arguments.

If running it from command line, try this:

`"ts-node -O '{\"module\": \"commonjs\", \"target\": \"ES6\" }' ./path/to/MyFile.ts"`

If that doesn't work, ditch ts-node and just use `tsc & node ./dist/MyFile.js`